# Mesmo pop up em várias páginas

Tags: php, javascript, html, jsp, popup

No meu projeto, o usuário pode fazer login de qualquer página em que estiver. Eu poderia construir o mesmo pop up em cada uma das páginas, mas gostaria de saber se existe alguma maneira de eu construir o pop up em um arquivo separado e só chamá-lo nos links das páginas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

se for PHP, vocé pode usar:

```
include_once('nome_do_arquivo_popup.php') no template principal.
```

caso não haja template principal, use o

```
include_once('nome_do_arquivo_popup.php')
```

em todos os arquivos. Dessa forma, você estará atingindo o seu objetivo.